# How to save datas(appointments) in the schedulers cell from a custom appointment form

Tags: c#, devexpress

Hii,

I am using devexpress xtrascheduler.
I have created a form instead of the default appointment form.(ie,while double clicking a form which is created by me is opening).Now i want to save the appoinments in my form to the scheduler cells(like when we add new appouintments ,it will show in the scheduler cell).how it can be done.
help me please...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [How to: Create a Custom EditAppointment Form with Custom Fields](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2288) topic in this regard.  It explains how this is done and contains a code which should be helpful to you.

Comment: I am a fresher in c#.so when i tried the code it is having an error.ie,it shows error on MyAppointmentformController=control.The error showing is that there is no reference for the MyAppointmentformController...But the problem is i dont want to use the entire devexpress application.so please help me to give a simple reference for MyAppointmentformController to save the data in the scheduler cell......I have only the scheduler control and a custom form that i created in my application